# HTML5 video tag IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, html5-video

I added a popup link with a html5 video tag. Seems working on all browsers but on IE9 i get a blank video and then i have to right-click on it and then play. Seems very confusing cause the video container its not visible.
[blank video container http://www.static2.descuentalomallorca.com/uploads/2.jpg](http://www.static2.descuentalomallorca.com/uploads/2.jpg)
click on the left image of the page
[image to video http://www.static2.descuentalomallorca.com/uploads/1.jpg](http://www.static2.descuentalomallorca.com/uploads/1.jpg)
I also tried to insert a poster but i get the same result... any chance?

http://84.127.79.26.dyn.user.ono.com/LocutoresBU/es/component/content/article/423-got2b-blowdry-kit.html

Answer (score 0):

Slider.js has an error in the code, which is probably messing up everything else on the page. console.log isn't supported in IE.

```
Line: 204
Character: 31
Code: 0
Error Message: 'console' is undefined
URL: http://84.127.79.26.dyn.user.ono.com/LocutoresBU/modules/mod_djimageslider/assets/slider.js
```

Try fixing that first and see if it works.